# Can the csv data be saved in dictionary for multiprocessing to save I/O operations and speed up the process?

Tags: python

I have around 1500 csv files with OHLC data of stock which contains 90000-100000 rows each.
Below the multiprocessing code to process each of the files ( with number of iterations ). When I tried to use 16 processess, my system started to hang a bit. I am very sure that its because of high use of I/O devices ( since system has to open each and every file ). Is it a good idea to save all the 1500 csv files to one one Dictionary and then run the code ? Can it reduce the time or slow down the hanging process ?
Also, system is working fine on 10 processes.
Here is the ohlc data look like -

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsk5W.png)

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import multiprocessing
import datetime
import itertools
import time
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# bank nifty
bn_futures = pd.read_csv('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Bank Nifty Index\\BankNifty_Futures GFDL 2011-2020.csv')
bn_futures['Date_time'] = bn_futures['Date'] + ' ' + bn_futures['Time']
bn_futures['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(bn_futures['Date_time'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
bn_futures = bn_futures[bn_futures['Date_time'].dt.date > datetime.date(2016,5,26)]
req_cols = [x for x in bn_futures.columns if 'Unnamed' not in x]
bn_futures = bn_futures[req_cols]
bn_futures['straddle'] = round(bn_futures['Close'],-2)
bn_futures['straddle'] = bn_futures['straddle'].astype(int)
bn_futures['straddle'] = bn_futures['straddle'].astype(str)
bn_futures['Date'] = bn_futures['Date_time'].dt.date
dates = list(set(bn_futures['Date'].to_list()))
dates.sort()

option_files1 = os.listdir('E:\\\\2nd Set\\')
option_files = []
for i in option_files1:
    if datetime.datetime.strptime(i.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%d').date() >= datetime.date(2016,5,27):
        option_files.append(i)

def time_loop(start_time,end_time,timeframe):
    start_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today().date(),start_time)  
    end_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today().date(),end_time)
    difference = int((((end_datetime - start_datetime).total_seconds())/60)/timeframe)
    final_time_list = []
    for i in range(difference):
        
        final_time_list.append((start_datetime+datetime.timedelta(minutes=i*timeframe)).time())
    return final_time_list
entry_time_list = time_loop(datetime.time(9,19),datetime.time(15,19),5)
sl_list = np.arange(1.1, 2, 0.1)
# sl_list = list(range(1.1,2,0.1))

paramlist = list(itertools.product(entry_time_list,sl_list))

def strategy(main_entry_time,sl):
    print(main_entry_time,sl)
    main_dict = {}
    for file in option_files:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(file.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
        try:
            # reading current date bn futures
            bn = bn_futures[bn_futures['Date'] == date]
            # reading main time bn futures
            b = bn[bn['Date_time'].dt.time == main_entry_time]
            straddle_value = b['straddle'].iloc[0]
            df = pd.read_csv('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Bank nifty Intraday All expiries\\2nd Set\\'+file)  
            df['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_time'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
            h = [k for k in df.columns if 'Un' not in k]
            df = df[h]
            total_df =  df[(df['Ticker'].str.contains(straddle_value)) & (df['Expiry_number'] == 0)  & (df['W/M'] == 'W')]
            option_types = ['CE','PE']
            for option in option_types:

                option_df = total_df[(total_df['Ticker'].str.contains(option)) & (total_df['Date_time'].dt.time == main_entry_time)]
                entry_price = option_df['Close'].iloc[0]
                strike = option
                entry_time = main_entry_time
                trade_df = total_df[(total_df['Ticker'].str.contains(option)) & (total_df['Date_time'].dt.time > main_entry_time)]
                trade_df.sort_values(by='Date_time',inplace=True)
                for t in trade_df.index:
                    if trade_df['Date_time'][t].time() > entry_time:
                        if trade_df['High'][t] > entry_price * sl:
                            exit_price = entry_price * sl
                            exit_time = trade_df['Date_time'][t].time()
                            profit = entry_price - exit_price - 0.02* entry_price         
                            main_dict['SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time)+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'_'+option] = {'Entry_date':str(date),'Entry_time':entry_time,'Strike':str(straddle_value)+option,'Entry_price':entry_price,'Exit_price':exit_price,'exit_time':exit_time,'profit':profit,'Reason':'SL'}
                            break
                        if trade_df['Date_time'][t].time() >= datetime.time(15,14,0):
                            exit_price = trade_df['Close'][t]
                            exit_time = trade_df['Date_time'][t].time()
                            profit = entry_price - exit_price - 0.02* entry_price
                            main_dict['SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time)+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'_'+option] = {'Entry_date':str(date),'Entry_time':entry_time,'Strike':str(straddle_value)+option,'Entry_price':entry_price,'Exit_price':exit_price,'exit_time':exit_time,'profit':profit,'Reason':'EOD'}   
                            break

        except Exception as yy:
            pass
    final_dict = dict(main_dict)
    final_df = pd.DataFrame(final_dict)
    final_df = final_df.transpose()
    final_df.to_csv('SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time).replace(':','')+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'.csv')
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    # mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    # main_dict = mgr.dict()
    total_data = paramlist
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=10)
    p.starmap(strategy,total_data)
    p.close()
```

Comment: What platform are you running under, Windows, Lunux, something else? You be tagging your question with *multiprocessing* and the platform you are running on.

Comment: I am using Windows and running it on VS Code

Comment: Python in windows copies entire parent process when multiprocessing so that's not very efficient. Also the main reason of the slowdown seems to be the innermost for loop which you should be able to get rid of using various pandas methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you can improve the multiprocessing performance, you should make sure your serial implementation is as efficient as it can be. Have you done that?

Your `strategy` method now is rereading every option file repeatedly for each element of `total_data` that is being passed to it. This is highly inefficient but moreover it might be contributing significantly to what is stalling your I/O (it depends on caching, which I discuss later). What if the data was put in a database and read up front and perhaps stored in a dictionary initialized at the beginning?

As far as `strategy` writing out the CSV file, it should be returning the input parameters and the `final_df` back to the main process so it can do all the I/O. For this function `imap_unordered` with a suitable *chunksize* argument is better suited so that the main process can write the results as they become available. Because we are no longer using method `starmap`, `strategy` will now be passed a tuple that will have to be unpacked:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
import multiprocessing
import datetime
import itertools
import time
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

# bank nifty
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bn_futures = pd.read_csv('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Bank Nifty Index\\BankNifty_Futures GFDL 2011-2020.csv')
    bn_futures['Date_time'] = bn_futures['Date'] + ' ' + bn_futures['Time']
    bn_futures['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(bn_futures['Date_time'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    bn_futures = bn_futures[bn_futures['Date_time'].dt.date > datetime.date(2016,5,26)]
    req_cols = [x for x in bn_futures.columns if 'Unnamed' not in x]
    bn_futures = bn_futures[req_cols]
    bn_futures['straddle'] = round(bn_futures['Close'],-2)
    bn_futures['straddle'] = bn_futures['straddle'].astype(int)
    bn_futures['straddle'] = bn_futures['straddle'].astype(str)
    bn_futures['Date'] = bn_futures['Date_time'].dt.date
    dates = list(set(bn_futures['Date'].to_list()))
    dates.sort()
    
    option_files1 = os.listdir('E:\\\\2nd Set\\')
    option_files = []
    for i in option_files1:
        if datetime.datetime.strptime(i.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%d').date() >= datetime.date(2016,5,27):
            option_files.append(i)
    
    def time_loop(start_time,end_time,timeframe):
        start_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today().date(),start_time)  
        end_datetime = datetime.datetime.combine(datetime.datetime.today().date(),end_time)
        difference = int((((end_datetime - start_datetime).total_seconds())/60)/timeframe)
        final_time_list = []
        for i in range(difference):        
            final_time_list.append((start_datetime+datetime.timedelta(minutes=i*timeframe)).time())
        return final_time_list
    entry_time_list = time_loop(datetime.time(9,19),datetime.time(15,19),5)
    sl_list = np.arange(1.1, 2, 0.1)
    # sl_list = list(range(1.1,2,0.1))

    paramlist = list(itertools.product(entry_time_list,sl_list))
    
def init_pool_processes(o_f):
    global option_files
    option_files = o_f

def strategy(tpl):
    main_entry_time, sl = tpl # unpack tuple
    print(main_entry_time,sl)
    main_dict = {}
    for file in option_files:
        date = datetime.datetime.strptime(file.split('.')[0],'%Y-%m-%d').date()
        try:
            # reading current date bn futures
            bn = bn_futures[bn_futures['Date'] == date]
            # reading main time bn futures
            b = bn[bn['Date_time'].dt.time == main_entry_time]
            straddle_value = b['straddle'].iloc[0]
            df = pd.read_csv('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Bank nifty Intraday All expiries\\2nd Set\\'+file)  
            df['Date_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_time'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
            h = [k for k in df.columns if 'Un' not in k]
            df = df[h]
            total_df =  df[(df['Ticker'].str.contains(straddle_value)) & (df['Expiry_number'] == 0)  & (df['W/M'] == 'W')]
            option_types = ['CE','PE']
            for option in option_types:

                option_df = total_df[(total_df['Ticker'].str.contains(option)) & (total_df['Date_time'].dt.time == main_entry_time)]
                entry_price = option_df['Close'].iloc[0]
                strike = option
                entry_time = main_entry_time
                trade_df = total_df[(total_df['Ticker'].str.contains(option)) & (total_df['Date_time'].dt.time > main_entry_time)]
                trade_df.sort_values(by='Date_time',inplace=True)
                for t in trade_df.index:
                    if trade_df['Date_time'][t].time() > entry_time:
                        if trade_df['High'][t] > entry_price * sl:
                            exit_price = entry_price * sl
                            exit_time = trade_df['Date_time'][t].time()
                            profit = entry_price - exit_price - 0.02* entry_price         
                            main_dict['SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time)+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'_'+option] = {'Entry_date':str(date),'Entry_time':entry_time,'Strike':str(straddle_value)+option,'Entry_price':entry_price,'Exit_price':exit_price,'exit_time':exit_time,'profit':profit,'Reason':'SL'}
                            break
                        if trade_df['Date_time'][t].time() >= datetime.time(15,14,0):
                            exit_price = trade_df['Close'][t]
                            exit_time = trade_df['Date_time'][t].time()
                            profit = entry_price - exit_price - 0.02* entry_price
                            main_dict['SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time)+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'_'+option] = {'Entry_date':str(date),'Entry_time':entry_time,'Strike':str(straddle_value)+option,'Entry_price':entry_price,'Exit_price':exit_price,'exit_time':exit_time,'profit':profit,'Reason':'EOD'}   
                            break

        except Exception as yy:
            pass
    #final_dict = dict(main_dict) # why make a copy?
    final_df = pd.DataFrame(main_dict)
    final_df = final_df.transpose()
    #final_df.to_csv('SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time).replace(':','')+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'.csv')
    return (sl, date, final_df)

def compute_chunksize(iterable_size, pool_size):
    chunksize, remainder = divmod(iterable_size, 4 * pool_size)
    if remainder:
        chunksize += 1
    return chunksize
        
if __name__=='__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    # mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    # main_dict = mgr.dict()
    total_data = paramlist
    POOL_SIZE = 10
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(option_list,))
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(len(total_data), POOL_SIZE)
    results = p.imap_unordered(strategy, total_data, chunksize=chunksize)
    for sl, date, final_df in results:
        final_df.to_csv('SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time).replace(':','')+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'.csv')   
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Since your are running under Windows, as I have mentioned before, code at global scope will be executed by each pool process as part of its initialization and so it is inefficient to have code that is not required by your worker function, `strategy` at global scope that is not contained within a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block. So that is what I have done. Since your worker function does need to reference (for the time being until the issue I initially raised is addressed) `option_files`, I have used the *initializer* and *initargs* arguments of the `Pool` constructor so that after the `option_files` list is created *once* by the main process only, it will be copied to each process in the pool used to initialize a global variable `option_files`.

**But I cannot stress enough that you should figure out a way of eliminating the reading of the files in the `option_files` list repeatedly. Ideally, building a dictionary of some sort that can be passed as another argument to `init_process_pools` so that each pool process has access to a copy of the dictionary once constructed would be ideal.** **What might save you is that Windows will cache data. Depending on the cache size and the size of the CSV files, the I/O bottleneck may not be as big as a problem as it might otherwise be.**

In the meanwhile, you could experiment and force "single threading" of reading and writing of data by using a `multirprocessing.Lock` with the following changes. If Windows is caching all the reads after the first time you read all the option files, it will probably not make too big a difference. The posted code above, which single threads the writing, however, should help.

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    start_time = time.time()
    # mgr = multiprocessing.Manager()
    # main_dict = mgr.dict()
    total_data = paramlist
    POOL_SIZE = 10
    io_lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=POOL_SIZE, initializer=init_pool_processes, initargs=(option_list, io_lock))
    chunksize = compute_chunksize(len(total_data), POOL_SIZE)
    results = p.imap_unordered(strategy, total_data, chunksize=chunksize)
    for sl, date, final_df in results:
        with io_lock:
            final_df.to_csv('SL_'+str(sl)+'entry_time_'+str(main_entry_time).replace(':','')+'entry_date_'+str(date)+'.csv')   
    p.close()
    p.join()
```

And:

```py
def init_pool_processes(o_f, lock):
    global option_files, io_lock
    option_files = o_f
    io_lock = lock
```

And finally:

```py
def stratgey(tpl):
   ...
            straddle_value = b['straddle'].iloc[0]
            with io_lock:
                df = pd.read_csv('E:\\Tanmay\\Data\\Bank nifty Intraday All expiries\\2nd Set\\'+file)
```

Comment: That was a very nice explanation. Will be of great help. I will focus on each of them slowly and try to speed up the code first on sequential basis.